# Iterating through functions using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I currently have multiple functions as below:

```
vect_1 = CountVectorizer(parameters)
vect_2 = CountVectorizer(parameters)
vect_3 = CountVectorizer(parameters)
vect_3 = CountVectorizer(parameters)
```

which I am trying to iterate each one of them. I've tried:

```
for i in range(4):
    vect = vect_[i]
    print vect
```

And I am struggling to correctly defining 'vect' part as it just becomes a string. Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: Don't try to do this. Use a list.

Comment: why don't you put them in a list/tuple? `vect = [CountVectorizer(parameters), ...]`

Comment: You don't have "multiple functions", you have multiple __variables__.

Answer (score 5):

This is the pythonic way to do it, using a list:

```
vects = [
    CountVectorizer(parameters),
    CountVectorizer(parameters),
    CountVectorizer(parameters),
    CountVectorizer(parameters)
]

for v in vects:
    print(v)
```

Whenever you see that variable names are being generated dynamically from strings, that's a warning that you need a better data structure to represent your data. Like a list, or a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not this, but try `globals` (in def use `locals`):

```
for i in range(1,5):
    vect = globals()['vect_%s'%i]
    print(vect)
```

Although still the most pythonic way is using @Oscar's solution

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you shouldn't do this. Use a list from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using list or dict

```
def func_a(a):
    print(a)


def func_b(b):
    print(b, b)


def func_c(c):
    print(c, c, c)


def func_d(d):
    print(d, d, d, d)


# use list
func_list = [func_a, func_b, func_c, func_d]
for i in range(4):
    func_list[i](i)

# use dict
func_dict = {"vect_1": func_a,
             "vect_2": func_b,
             "vect_3": func_c,
             "vect_4": func_d}
for i in range(1, 5):
    func_dict["vect_" + str(i)](i)
```

which will print

```
0
1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3 3
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

Comment: A dictionary with integer keys? A list would be a better fit anyway. I'd agree to use a dictionary if the keys are `'vect_1'`, `'vect_2'`, etc., to mirror the variables in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through all your parameters.

```
vectors = []
parameters = []
#Put code for adding parameters here

for parameter in parameters:
    vectors.append(CountVectorizer(parameter))
```

This loops through the parameters you have set and runs the function with each parameter. You can now access all the outputs from the vectors list.